# How do I use a DLL function in C# without adding the DLL as reference?

Tags: c#, dll, namespaces, declaration

I'm trying to use functions from a DLL that can't be added as Reference through Visual Studio (a message saying "reference cannot be added" appears). However, I've gotten instructions from the creator of the DLL and they suggested I use them like this in VB.Net:

```
Private Declare Function Prn_Init Lib "VAx_VPOS396_APPAPI.dll" () As Integer
```

That works, but now I want to write a program in C#. How do I "translate" that declaration to C#?

Additional: In C++ the declaration comes in a *.h file with these lines:

```
#ifndef  _VPOS396DLL_API_H
#define  _VPOS396DLL_API_H
VPOS396_DLL_API     int Prn_Init(void);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should create the method(s) you want to use in C#, make them `extern` and add a `[DllImport]` attribute. For example:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern bool Beep(uint dwFreq, uint dwDuration);
```

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984739%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: I used this (with "private" added before "static") but I'm getting a "cannot PInvoke" error. At this rate I might have to refer to the C++ sample. Can a C++ *.h file be used in a C# file? And how?

Comment: @Yves what is the exact error you're getting? Did you place the dll in the same folder as the .NET executable? Does the dll have additional dependencies, and did you include them too?

Answer (score 0):

[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("VAx_VPOS396_APPAPI.dll")]

public static extern unsafe Int32 Prn_Init(void);

("unsafe" is optional)

Comment: Please format your code and try to refrain from code only answers.